# Error message "ActiveX component can't create object" appears for all objects

Tags: excel, vba

I'm unable to create any objects in an Excel macro I am trying to write.  Initially I was trying to work with MSXML2.DOMDocument60, however, I realized that i'm not able to get ActiveX to create any objects.  For example, I get the same error (Run-time 429 'ActiveX component can't create object') for this line of code:

```
Dim ExcelSheet As Object
Set ExcelSheet = CreateObject("Excel.Sheet")
```

Obviously since i'm in excel, the program is installed correctly and it should have access to it.  I've checked several other Stackoverflow pages for this.  It doesn't appear to be an issue with a reference and I can't imagine the simple code above not working because of missing dlls since I am again already in Excel.

Is there possibly a security feature on my computer blocking this action?

Again,  my issue is not with the above code.  This was just a simple way to show that Create object is not working.

My main goal is to get the following to work:
Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument60")

I've already verified that I have the correct reference and I re-registered the Dlls.

Comment: Excel worksheet objects require you to "attach" to an existing worksheet, whether it's one already present in the workbook or a worksheet you've newly created. So use something like `Dim thisWS as Worksheet; Set thisWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: Hi PeterT.   Thank you for your response.  Unfortunately, that doesn't address my issue.  The code above was just intended as an example.  The real issue is that i appear to be blocked anytime I use "CreateObject" and I'm not sure why.  I run into the same issue trying to create an object for a word document: 

Dim oWordApp As Word.Application 
Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Comment: Are you using a Mac?

Comment: Hi Tim.  No.  I am on a Windows 10 machine with a 64- bit Operating system.  The version of excel i'm using is Microsoft 2016 and it is 32 bit.

Comment: Why are you late-binding `ExcelSheet` if you're in Excel? The type library is already referenced, have you tried seenig what happens when you do `Set ExcelSheet = New Excel.Worksheet`?

Comment: Mathieu,

That was only an example.  I was using that to show that even the simplest CreateObject code is not working for me.  What i'm really trying to do is work with XML.

The actual code is this:
Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument60")

I was reluctant to include that initially, because i was worried that people were going to suggest that I try things which I've already verified such as that I do have the correct reference and that I verified that the DLLs are correct.   My only issue is with CreateObject

Comment: See, asking about X when you mean Y is always a bad idea.

Comment: Again though, why are you using `CreateObject` to create instances of types that are already early-bound, instead of `New`ing them up?

Comment: i just tried it on my machine: i got the same error, for some reason there is an Issue with the "60" in the reference. This site: https://bettersolutions.com/vba/xml/microsoft-xml.htm suggests using `MSXML2.DOMDocument`, and this works for me.  
Edit: @MathieuGuindon already wrote this in his answer (with explanation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for.  My company has the C drive and another network drive locked down, which prevents CreateObject from working when an excel sheet is saved to either of these locations. By saving the excel sheet to my desktop instead I am able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

There's no class with an `Excel.Sheet` progID in the Excel object model. You probably meant `Excel.Worksheet`, but that won't work either, and it's not because of `CreateObject` or any kind of obscure security feature.

Simply put, not all classes/types are *creatable*: In the Excel type library `Application` is, and that's about it: everything else needs to be created within the object model, using the factory methods provided by that API.

In other words the only way you can create an `Excel.Worksheet`, is if Excel creates it for you.

```
Set excelSheet = Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
```

Same with an `Excel.Workbook`:

```
Set excelBook = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Add
```

There *are* other ways (e.g. copying an existing `Worksheet` without specifying a `Target` argument will create a new `Workbook` that contains a copy of that source `Worksheet`), but rule of thumb if you can't `New` up a class in a referenced type library, there's little chance `CreateObject` can do any better (unless the type registration explicitly prevents early-binding usage).

---

The question was edited, but this answer stands: don't use `CreateObject` to create instances of classes that are already resolved and readily available.

```
Set objXml = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60 'works fine
```

If you *really* want to use `CreateObject`, then you need to use progID strings that exist in your registry.

```
Set objXml = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument60") ' blows up on my machine as well
Set objXml = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument") ' works fine
```

But using `CreateObject` to create an instance of a class the compiler already knows about, is a very, very roundabout way to do this.

Comment: Hi Mathieu,

The "New" keyword approach does work for me.  Neither example of CreateObject works for me though.  I know I have gotten that to work on other computers, and based on other examples that approach does work for other people.   I would really like to know why it doesn't work with my current machine, but for now I will continue to use the "New" method instead.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How `CreateObject` works, is that it takes the provided string ProgID (or class GUID), finds that ProgID/GUID in the registry, locates the type library on disk, finds the type, inside that library, creates an instance of it, and yields it to the caller. If it works somewhere else but not on your machine, you might need to repair/reinstall whatever installed the library you're using. Early binding loads the type library and binds types and member calls at compile-time (hence "eary") - prefer early binding whenever you can.